# Sharepoint 2013 workflow not firing when document checked in but works if checked out

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sharepointdocumentlibrary

We have a document library that has both Document sets and Documents. We also have a Workflow that is manually started by the user on any item in this library. The problem we are having is that the workflow doesn't start if the document is checked in and . If the document is checked out, it works fine. The workflow runs fine on a Document Set.

Looking into the log files, I see the following messages:

Skip lookup field SortBehavior as it's not dependent lookup, but it has PrimaryFieldId ID   46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe
Skip lookup field CheckedOutUserId as it's not dependent lookup, but it has PrimaryFieldId ID 46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe
Skip lookup field SyncClientId as it's not dependent lookup, but it has PrimaryFieldId ID   46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe 
The target list of field Taxonomy Catch All Column, TaxCatchAll, does not exists in the current web or the current user does not have permissioin to see it. Skip it.   46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe

Immediately below these lines, I see the following message:
The file "http://sharepointurl.com/abc/TestWf/select_element.pdf" is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes......

The workflow is very simple and only logs a test message. I am not sure why SharePoint is trying to check-out the document but I have a feeling that it has something to do with the above messages.

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to fix the issue after getting some support on Microsoft TechNet forum.

Assuming the workflow is a SharePoint Designer Workflow, Open SharePoint Designer and Connect to your site. Click on Workflows from the left navigation, and click on your workflow. Workflow information page will open. In the "Settings" area in the right pane, uncheck the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name". This will fix the problem.

Comment: I followed your workaround in my test environment, then forgot about it when I deployed to production... now I've found your post again to fix my production problem. This should not be happening, Microsoft.